# How do I parse an unusual date string

Tags: c#

Hello I have an unusual date format that I would like to parse into a DateTime object

```
string date ="20101121";  // 2010-11-21
string time ="13:11:41:  //HH:mm:ss
```

I would like to use `DateTime.Tryparse()` but I cant seem to get started on this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the date allways having the same number of characters, i mean, the month and day are allways 2 digit long?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string date ="20101121"; // 2010-11-21
string time ="13:11:41"; //HH:mm:ss

DateTime value;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    date + time,
    "yyyyMMddHH':'mm':'ss", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out value))
{
    Console.Write(value.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Date parse failed!");
}
```

**Edit:** Wrapped the time separator token in single quotes as per Frédéric's comment

Comment: beware of the `:` character in date/time format strings: it's the [time separator token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and it can surprise you, e.g. by resolving to the `.` character in Italian locales. You might want to wrap it inside single quotes to escape it and avoid trouble later on :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) static method with a [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
using System.Globalization;

string date = "20101121"; // 2010-11-21
string time = "13:11:41"; // HH:mm:ss

DateTime convertedDateTime;
bool conversionSucceeded = DateTime.TryParseExact(date + time,
    "yyyyMMddHH':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

DateTime.TryParseExact()