# Parsing custom date formats (c#)

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

An api im using is providing me a date. This date is of type `string` and is presented in the format:

> *`Mon Nov 16 19:15:09 +0000 2009`*

`DateTime.TryParse()` fails when this value is provided. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse an unusual date string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238888/how-do-i-parse-an-unusual-date-string)

Comment: If you are guarenteed the string will have this form you can format it into a acceptble string that can be parsed into DateTime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx See remarks for accepted strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `DateTimeOffset` class in order to handle the offset.

```
[TestMethod]
public void test()
{
  string s = "Mon Nov 16 19:15:09 +0000 2009";

  var result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    s, 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  Assert.AreEqual(16, result.Day);
  Assert.AreEqual(11, result.Month);
  Assert.AreEqual(2009, result.Year);
  Assert.AreEqual(19, result.Hour);
  Assert.AreEqual(15, result.Minute);
  Assert.AreEqual(9, result.Second);
  Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Offset.Hours);    
}
```

Change the offset in the string - e.g. '0600' and then change the offset assertion to match, it'll work.

You can then convert this into a `DateTime` if you have to - but you lose the offset information; so you have to decide whether you're going to keep it as the original local time (`19:15:09`), or if you're going to convert to some standard time (e.g. `13:19:05 UTC` if offset is `+06:00`).

It gets interesting if you need to convert that to your own local time - because it would depend on what DST rules were in place in 2009 at that time of the year - that can cause a real headache!

So, if you're going to `DateTime` I recommend converting to universal time and then go from there.  Add this to the test:

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
//little bit long winded - but you need the 'Universal' Kind for reliability
Console.WriteLine(
  DateTime.SpecifyKind(
    new DateTime(result.ToUniversalTime().Ticks), 
    DateTimeKind.Utc)
);
```

This outputs:

> 11/16/2009 19:15:09 +06:00
>
> 11/16/2009 13:15:09

Comment: Nice, never figured you could do the DateTime format in reverse.

Comment: @Ingó: Quite, the pain of the minutiae of this has been etched on my mind from previous projects.  Dates and Times cause far too much trouble!

Comment: Note that there is a nice library called NodaTime that makes time zone intricacies explicit (and thus easier to get right): http://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 2):

Try [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) passing a suitable format string.

Answer (score 0):

One of the TryParse methods accepts an IFormatProvider, which can also come as a DateTimeFormatInfo class. The following link has all the necessary details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx

Yours would be almost like: ddd, MMM dd yyyy HH':'mm':'ss zzz yyyy

The only problem is the timezone offset, zzz includes a colon between the hours and minutes. You might get away with using zz'00' though it is cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Because the DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse the string representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture, trying to parse a particular string across different cultures can either fail or return different results. If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales, use the [DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method or one of the overloads of the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) method and provide a format specifier.